# Directing based on button's handler condition

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can i add an if/else condition on the button's handler..So that if a condition is true, i direct the button to a certain function (submit), else to another function (submit1).

```
var btn_submitform = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            width:75,
            height:30,
            text:'Submit', 
            id:"btn_submitform",
            handler: submit
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check on that condition in the handler:

```
onSubmit: function(button, event, eOpts) {
    if(true) {
        this.function1();
        //
        this.fireEvent('event1', [button, event, eOpts]);
    }
    else {
        this.function2();
        //
        this.fireEvent('event2', [button, event, eOpts]);
}
```

or bind a handler based on that condition (in a controller for example):

```
var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[id=btn_submitform]')[0];

if(true) {
    button.on('click', 'function1');
}
else {
    button.on('click', 'function2');
}
```

or create a delegate:

```
var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form')[0];

form.addListener({
    // Ext.Buttons have an xtype of 'button', so we use that are a selector for our delegate
    delegate: 'button',

    click: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        if (button.id === 'btn_submitform') {
            alert('Submit button tapped!');
        }
        else {
            alert('Other button tapped!');
        }
    }
});
```